# Clarify my doubts in testNG annotation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
**Class 1:**                                   **Class 2:**

@BeforeTest                                    @Test
public void browserSetup(){                    public void testCase2(){
   ...                                            ...
}                                              }

@Test                                          @Test
public void testCase1(){                       public void testCase3(){
   ...                                               ...
}                                              }

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(){
   ...
}
```

In this two class is my selenium java code structure. Here class 1 execute browserSetup, testcase 1 and tearDown. Here my doubt is how to execute "tearDown" method, after class 2 methods.

I want to run this program like below,
1. browserSetup
2. testCase1
3. tearDown
4. testCase2
5. tearDown
6. testCase3
7. tearDown

Any solution for this?

Comment: change `@AfterMethod` to `@AfterClass`

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to associate a particular teardown method to a particular @Test method, there is no need for annotations: Simply call it at the end of your test method in a finally:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    try {
        // test something
    } finally {
        someParticularTearDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you can write a small function which is doing a tearDown() functionality and explicitly call it after every testClass().

Comment: My program's output is single html output, my all(two class) test case's final results mark in tearDown method. So I want to combain both class.

Comment: AfterMethod works, but i dont know how to combain both class. If i combain both class using "extends" key word. My all test cases are skipped.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
          <class name="Class1Pack.Class1"/>
          <class name="Class1Pack.Class2"/>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>

This is my TestNG XML. Any worng in that?

Comment: Extends will not work. You will have to call it in using Testng.xml something like 
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TestAll">
 <test name="testcasename">
  <classes>
   <class name="com.package.testng.examples.suite.test1" />
   <class name="com.package.testng.examples.suite.test2" />
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance for that:

**Mother class:**

```
@BeforeTest                                 
public void browserSetup(){                
   ...                                        
}   

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(){
   ...
}
```

**Class 1:**

```
@Test                                         
public void testCase1(){                 
   ...                                      
}
```

**Class 2:**

```
@Test
public void testCase2(){
   ...                                            
}                                              

@Test                                       
public void testCase3(){
   ...                                           
}
```